# How to disable positioning of p:overlayPanel?

Tags: primefaces

I need to center my OverlayPanel in my screen.

```
            -----------
            | Button  |
            -----------
    -------------------
    |   OverlayPanel  |
    -------------------
```

Here's my code:

```
<p:overlayPanel id="overlayPanelId" for="panelBtnId" hideEffect="fade" dynamic="true" dismissable="true">               
    <ui:include src="/faces/OverlayMiniSearch.xhtml"/>
</p:overlayPanel>
```

Comment: Did you read https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/overlaypanel?id=positioning ?

Comment: @JasperdeVries Yes, and it's dynamic. I want to make it fixed in my webview, for example: centered in the page.

Comment: I doubt you can with the positioning get it central in your screen. Only solution that might work is to not use the `for` attribute, but use the javascript `show(target)` where target is your `body`

Comment: @JasperdeVries I tried this solution but it gives the same behavior. Any other solution?!

Comment: Yes, use a dialog? Or try with CSS to override the position

Comment: @Kukeltje thank you, I made it with: "top: inherit !important;"  in css

Comment: But really, a dialog is the tool for the job here. That saves you from creating hacks and workarounds. The cleaner your application is, the easier it is to maintain / upgrade.